# Illegal power connection, how should I handle this situation?

Tags: electrical-panel, extension-cord, structure

I saw a yellow (old flat style) extension cord wired to a power pole way above the meter and then the cord dropped to the front of the structure and was wired to the base of an unmounted porch light.

There is a massive droop in the cord that put it at about 4 ft from the ground before rising again to the fixture (exaggerated drip loop) - the occupants regularly duck under the cord bump it as they navigate around the trailer to carry out normal tasks.

Legalities and codes aside, **how** do I convince these people that they are in **serious danger** with every item they plug in?

I know they power a water pump, stove, fridge, microwave, 2 tvs and various other lights and appliances from information shared in the course of normal interaction (I have never been inside but as the lightweight gauge of that wire is constantly on my mind, anytime one of the occupants mention an appliance or various outlets in the trailer that have just "stopped" working, I get overwhelmed with fear). I do not want to alienate the people or let on that I realize their power hookup is not as it should be (a mixture of fear for retaliation as they obviously do not have a high enough regard for the law to have the power hooked up). I did mention the wire in passing one day asked what it was and was told "oh it was that way when we moved in", so I did not pursue it at that time.

My gut is in knots over this. My silence could result in 2 young wet behind the ears young adults **die**. and maybe it is possible they are ignorant enough to not realize the actual **danger** they may be in. I am looking for suggestions to enlighten them and encourage a remedy that does not ruin the rest of their lives being in jail or debt from fines, but I fear their actual lives are in the balance.

Comment: Make an anonymous call to the local building code enforcement authority. If you can't find them or don't get a response, anonymously call the *non-emergency* line to the local fire department and report it as a dangerous condition.

Comment: There's no way in and of itself you are going to feel like a winner on both sides of this, and to be honest, that's not what is important. If this wire is in plain sight, then call The electric company, the fire department, or the trailer/municipality and report it. The people aren't going to like it, but if it is disturbing you then put your mind at ease. Plain sight, you are being a good citizen.

Comment: Is the power cable from the utility to the pole overhead or underground?

Comment: "extension cord wired to a power pole way above the meter" - so I assume that the extension cord is connected prior to the meter, which means they are stealing power. The utility company would be very interested in this, and would quickly put a stop to it if they were informed.

Comment: is the wire warm? if not, it's not overloaded. you admit you don't know what kind of power conditioning/handling they run in the house, so i don't think it's assured that "lives are in the balance". it sounds more ugly than dangerous. if you think that warrants they go without power, call it in. fwiw, i used to be a code zealot until i lived in mexico and see what they use 24x7...

Comment: Bring them a housewarming gift.  Skewers, marshmallows, graham crackers and chocolate.

Comment: Old yellow Flat Style - sounds like Romex cable .. if they are walking under it at 4 feet above the ground - call your power company and ask them to come out and look at it - and that you are concerned because it looks dangerous drooping 4 feet above the ground (which it is dangerous - because there is a guy wire steel cable that is supposed to handle the strain of that wire from pole to house). Call and just tell them you are concerned  for the safety of anyone in and around that home. The power company will not bite you (except on your own bill :-) ).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly you are concerned but it is not your job to fix everyone.

So even if they have a house fire tonight it is not your fault.

The best thing to do is to get someone with authority to take a look.

Here in the US we feel safe enough to call police.  They are always concerned about safety.

But here in the US nobody would ever do that, at least not in the cities.

So wherever you are I'd bet you can figure out the best place to call.

I would suggest the power company.   Or the fire department.

All you would have to do is ID yourself as a concerned neighbor and repeat over the phone what you have written here.